# SQL Server 2012 - Openrowset - User without sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, system-administration, openrowset

Environment :

- Server : Windows Server 2012
- SQL Server : SQL Server 2012

I want to use openrowset in my production environment without granting sysadmin to the user. saw a lot of posts about this issue but non seem to provide a solution to mine.

I performed the following steps:

1. Created a non administrator windows account
2. Created a windows authentication login in my database (not sysadmin)
3. Enabled 'show advanced options','ad hoc distributed queries'
4. Verified 'Disallow adhoc access' is disabled in the provider (key does not exist in the registry)
5. Enabled driver

   ```
   USE [master] 
   GO 

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
   GO 

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
   GO
   ```

   1. Changed the user running the SQL server service to be Administraor
   2. Granted full permissions on the TEMP , TMP directory of the Administrator to the user created on Step1.

Whenever I run the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 8.0;Database=c:\temp\xxx.xls;','SELECT * FROM [xxx$]')
```

I get:

> Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' has been denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.

It does not seem to even try to access the file because whether it is there or not I get the same error. When I run it with the sysadmin user it works and when I try to query a non existing file I get error it can't find it in oppose to the non sysadmin user.

Maybe I am missing a permission on different directory or the the non sysadmin user is missing other permission.

Can you please advise?

Thanks
Doron

Comment: Try to grant `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` server level permission to the user you are using.

Comment: I added the Disallow adhoc access to the registry with 0 and it worked. even though it was disabled at SQL Server. Apparently  it consider it as true if the key does not exist.